# Terminal limiting cpu usage while running lua

Tags: node.js, lua, luajit

I was learning lua (specifically loops), and I need to run my code in the cmd to be able to use luaJit. Doing so, I notice that the loop were too slow. After that, I recreated the loop using js in the vscode and when I ran it, everything was normal. Then, I tried the same code, but compiled in the cmd, not surprising it was also slow. So, I think there is something limiting the cpu usage while running code in the terminal, but I have no idea. If someone knows how to fix it, I would be delighted.

All I did was open the terminal and run these commands:
`luajit <path-to-the-code>`
`node <path-to-the-code>`

Lua:
vscode: average 106 ms per test | 1.1 sec total
cmd: average 10 secs per test | 100 sec total

Js:
vscode: average 288 ms per test | 3 sec total
cmd: average 10 secs per test | 100 sec total

Lua code:

```
function test() 
    for x=1, 100000 do
        print(x/100)
    end 
end

totalTime = 0

for x=1, 10 do
    start = os.clock()
    test()
    totalTime = totalTime + os.clock() - start
end

print(totalTime/10)
```

Js code:

```
function test(){
    for(let x = 1; x<100000; x++){
        console.log(x/100)
    }
}

let totalTime = 0

for(x = 1; x!=10; x++){
    var start = Date.now()
    test()
    totalTime += Date.now()-start;
}

console.log(totalTime/10)
```

Comment: what is "too slow"? how fast is it supposed to be and how did you arrive at the that value? please include the code you are running or at least a minimal reproducible example for the issue you are seeing.

Comment: @Nifim when i ran it in vscode, it was completed in about 1 second. In the cmd, 100 seconds. Using js, the result was similiar. I will put the code in the question.

Comment: What and where are the commands you are using to invoke both of theses examples in `cmd.exe`? Without that information, we cannot assist you with a `cmd.exe` issue, and you should remove the [[tag:cmd]] tag, _(as it is currently unrelated to anything you've posted)_.

Comment: @compo, I wrote in the question the commands used. I selected the cmd tag because i want to know why the cmd is limiting the velocity of my code, but ok I will remove it.

Comment: I can guarantee that `luajit (path to lua code)`  and `node (path to js code)` are not the exact and actual commands you have used. All you have posted are psuedo commands which cannot be directly replicated by us, because we'd have to make guesses ourselves. Also when you provide code/commands in your question, you're supposed to format them as such, so that others easiliy identify them, and copy them as necessary.

Comment: Well, all I did was open the prompt and run luajit (the path to my .lua code). I did the same for node.js. I just started doing stuff outside of my IDE so I don't know about pseudo commands and pretty much anything. So, if you could recommend me what I should start studying, it would be helpful.